# How to connect PostgreSQL in a Spring Roo setup?

Tags: postgresql, spring-roo

I am using the script of the [spring.io/spring-roo/#running-from-shell](http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/#running-from-shell) fast guide, a 10 lines example.

The only modification is the `jpa setup --provider` line, changed to connect PostgreSQL (`HIBERNATE --database POSTGRES`). All the steps and code are at [this `roo_hello2pg.md` github document](https://github.com/ppKrauss/dummy-java-spring/blob/master/roo_hello2pg.md).

The [application.properties](https://github.com/ppKrauss/dummy-java-spring/blob/master/hello2pg/src/main/resources/application.properties) seems

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc\:postgresql\://localhost\:5432/hello2bd
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
```

What more I need? Some `spring.jpa.hibernate` lines?  The browser generates error "status=500" when use database (insert a value).

Comment: [edit] your question and add the **complete** error message (ideally with the stack trace of the exception). [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) text please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name, I included all generated files at the git, see [application.properties](https://github.com/ppKrauss/dummy-java-spring/blob/master/hello2pg/src/main/resources/application.properties) and others there... Sorry about error messages, only tomorow at office, was status 500 in the browser, the Maven compiled.

Comment: Please describe your environment: Roo version, JDK version, S.O, ... and the thrown error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I could see in your gitHub repository, you have configured your connection to the Postgres database correctly.

But did you create the `hello2db` database and the `Timer` table in your system?

As the Spring Boot documentation sais, JPA databases will be automatically created **only** if you use an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby)

Check http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-creating-and-dropping-jpa-databases

In your case, to create the database automatically using a Postgres DB, you should include the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop` property in the `application.properties` file.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks! the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop` line do de magic!